# How to join SQL query in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sum, left-join

How can I write second query instead of 'users_statistic' in first query?

```
SELECT * 
from 'users' LEFT JOIN 'users_statistic' 
ON users.id=users_statistic.user_id

SELECT *, SUM(clicks) as sum_clicks, SUM(page_views) as sum_page_views 
FROM 'users_statistic' 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Second query return table
user_id         sum_clicks            sum_page_clicks
1                                754                                                543
2                           234                                                  987

In table 'users' is field id, which equivalent user_id in table 'users_statistic'. Also there are no fields *sum_clicks* and *sum_page_clicks* in table 'users'. I want to add fields  *sum_clicks* and *sum_page_clicks* from second query to table 'users'

Comment: It isn't clear what your goal is here.  Please add sample data which explains what you are trying to do.  Note that your second query is technically invalid (at least according to ANSI SQL), as you are doing `SELECT *` along with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Added. And the second query is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the aggregation directly in the 1st query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(s.clicks), 0) sum_clicks, 
       COALESCE(SUM(s.page_views), 0) sum_page_views
FROM users u LEFT JOIN users_statistic s 
ON u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

I use `COALESCE()` so that you get `0` instead of `null` if for a user there are no clicks or page views.